# bi-daily, bidaily or twice-daily?

Tags: adjectives, time

I would like to say that a process happens two times a day, should I say:

- a twice-daily process
- a bi-daily process
- a bidaily process
  ?

Comment: *Twice-daily* is the usual term. The others are unestablished neologisms.

Comment: @Mick "bidaily" isn't a neologism. What about "biannual"?

Comment: Ngran shows very rare usages of "bidaily" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bidaily&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbidaily%3B%2Cc0 - Biannual is a common term: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bidaily%2C+biannual&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbidaily%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbiannual%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @SovereignSun Anyone can add words to Wiktionary and I don't see *bidaily* listed in other online dictionaries. Collins online dictionary lists [*bi-daily*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/2308/Bi-daily) as a new word suggestion. Status: rejected.

Comment: @Mick http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bidaily

Comment: @Mick http://www.yourdictionary.com/bidaily

Comment: @Mick http://www.abbreviations.com/bidaily and http://www.wordsense.eu/bidaily/

Comment: *b.d.: bis diem* -- twice daily. Not **bidaily,* which is at best a nonce word sometimes used for "twice a day" and sometimes for "once in two days," so exercise caution there. See: http://www.yourdictionary.com/bidaily  and "Amygdala-kindled rats were rendered tolerant to diazepam's anticonvulsant effect by 25 "bidaily" (one/48 h) diazepam injections (2.5 mg/kg), each followed 1 h later by a convulsive stimulation." at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7886085   (Note the scare quotes!)

Comment: @SovereignSun You are definitely on a roll today. ;-)

Comment: @Mick Trying to find some truth! I often see bidaily (not bi-daily or bi daily) in books and articles.

Comment: What about "bidiurnal"?

Comment: @SovereignSun It's probably good to use and anyone would understand it. It's odd that the big online dictionaries (e.g. Oxford, Cambridge) don't list it.

Comment: @Mick Oxford and Cambridge are too busy with other things ;-)

Comment: http://hull-awe.org.uk/index.php?title=Biennial_(clarification) - an interesting article.

Comment: You could always use the medical term "bid".

Comment: Despite it stipulatively meaning 'every-two', 'bi' as a prefix has a tendency to be used for both 'twice-a-' and 'every-two-'.  So I suggest not using bi-daily and using 'twice a day' or 'twice daily'.

Answer (score 8):

*Twice-daily* is probably the best choice since it is unambiguous and commonly used. Using either *bidaily* or *bi-daily* risks the reader getting muddled between "twice a day" and "every other day".

Neither the Oxford or Cambridge online dictionaries list *bidaily* or *bi-daily*, possibly for the reason given above. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/1627/bi-daily) lists *bi-daily* as a "new word suggestion" (status: rejected).

Whilst not exactly neologisms, *bidaily* and *bi-daily* haven't gained any traction as the following Ngram shows:

[image]

If we add "twice a day" into the mix, we get a much clearer picture:

[image]

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twice+a+day%2Ctwice-daily%2Cbi-daily%2Cbidaily&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwice%20a%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20-%20daily%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbi%20-%20daily%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbidaily%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Apart from not being present in main dictionaries, which tent to be lagger in this respect,  I'd suggest against using it because there is no evidence that as a neologism it has gained traction so far, if it ever will.

Comment: Er, I don't think so. *Semidaily* is every half-day just as *semiannual* is every half a year.  *Bidaily* is ever other day, just as *biannual* is every other year. See Kris’s medical example for proof.

Comment: @tchrist Aren't you confusing *biannual* with *biennial*? It seems that different dictionaries give different meanings--either one or the other, or both.

Comment: Oh bother, perhaps.

Comment: @tchrist Heh! All the more reason to stick with *twice-daily*. ;-)

Answer (score -3):

> Bidaily - Occurring twice in a day.

I think it's this what you've been looking for, yet, it's not a popular word.

And I guess it should be "twice daily" and not as one word. Like in:

- You should take two capsules twice daily if you want to recover.